# Timer is not triggering after one minute using jQuery or give some other solution to trigger function after every 1 min?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

```
 var setTimer;
 var isTimeSet = false;

 if (!isTimeSet) {
    setTimer = $('#hdn_timerTime').val();
    isTimeSet = true;
    
  }



initialTimer();
function initialTimer() {        
    var CustomMinutes = 60 * parseInt(setTimer),

        display = $('#time'); 
    startTimer(CustomMinutes, display);
}

function startTimer(duration, display) {
   
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {

        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.text(minutes + ":" + seconds);

        if (--timer < 0) {
         
            timer = duration;
            $('#outputmeters').val(JSON.stringify(listItem));
            // _hardMeter.UpdateMeterData();
            _hardMeter.TempUpdateMeterDataConfirmation();

        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

This code I am using but for the first time it work fine than after that it time start reducing and function fire very quickly. I don't know how it happening.

Please help me out in this and if you have some better solution for it. Could you please share it?

Comment: value for setTimer is 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` to call the same function repeatedly at set intervals until either the page is unloaded or you call `clearInterval`:

```
var timedFunction = function() {
  ... // Do something
}

setInterval(timedFunction, 60 * 1000);
```

If your timed function takes arguments which change each time, use `setTimeout` and call it within the function body as well

```
var timedFunctionWithArguments = function(iterations) {

  console.debug(iterations); // Do something

  setTimeout(timedFunctionWithArguments, 60 * 1000, iterations++);
}

timedFunctionWithArguments(0);
```

Comment: Everytime `timedFunction` is invoked, new interval will be created... that's bad.

Comment: Can anybody give me some other example of timer countdown after completion of countdown it should execute method and again reset to beginning and again countdown should begin